# CCLabelBMFont setString cause OpenGL error 0x0500

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x

Cocos2d: OpenGL error 0x0500 CCTextureAtlas.cpp drawNumberOfQuads 686

OpenGL will scroll error when I update word with setString. Or init the CCLabelBMFont with words.

```
cocos2d.x.version: cocos2d-x 2.2.6
cocos2d.x.compiled_with_profiler: false
cocos2d.x.compiled_with_gl_state_cache: true
gl.vendor: Apple Inc.
gl.renderer: Apple A8 GPU
gl.version: OpenGL ES 2.0 Apple A8 GPU - 50.6.10
gl.max_texture_size: 4096
gl.max_texture_units: 8
gl.max_samples_allowed: 4
gl.supports_PVRTC: true
gl.supports_NPOT: true
gl.supports_BGRA8888: false
gl.supports_discard_framebuffer: true
gl.supports_vertex_array_object: true
```

Comment: can you please paste your code ?  that would be much easier to understand .

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed thx, I finally fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem. It not cocos2dx problem.....

pool code cause :

```
void Box2dCCSprite::setOpacity(GLubyte opacity){
super::setOpacity(opacity);
if (m_pChildren) {
    for (int i=m_pChildren->count()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        CCSprite* child = dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>(m_pChildren->objectAtIndex(i));
        //CCSprite* child=(CCSprite*)m_pChildren->objectAtIndex(i);
        if (child) {
            child->setOpacity(opacity);
        }
    }
}
```

}

the comment is error code.

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed actually not all children are CCSprite

Comment: ohwkey , So you wanted  to set opacity only to those child who are CCsprites , Right ?? . .

Comment: @shaqirsaiyed yes